# Partial Key in RDBMS

Tags: key, rdbms

There are two tables Employee table and Employee's dependents table. Dependents have total participation and its weak entity. Here Owner entity is Employee. The dependent has many attributes like name,gender,dob,ssn. The dob for dependent is marked as partial key. Why?

What is Partial Key in RDBMS?
When we exactly use it? Is it dependent on week attributes?